# Declaring services in providers of multiple components

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am new to angular 2 and I'm working on it for a week or so. As per the best coding practices followed by our team, we declare our services in the providers of the root component.

I wonder, what if we declare our services in providers of multiple components?

Comment: That way it will create a new instance for that particular component component level.. Read [Hierarchical Dependency Injection](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection) here from docs

Comment: if you want to share data through a service, only then it is advised to add it to the providers of the root component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a service to the component provider will override the parent provider and will create a new instance of that service

here is an example 
i will assume that i have service called `MyService`

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    ....,
    imports: [MyService, ...]
})
```

**MyComponent1.ts**

```
@Component({
    ...,
    providers: [MyService]
})

export default class MyComponent1 {
    constructor(private Myservice myService) {

    }
}
```

**MyComponent2.ts**

```
export default class MyComponent2 {
    constructor(private Myservice myService) {

    }
}
```

`myService` in MyComponent1 and MyComponent2 are totally different

the one in `MyComponent1` is that one that was provided from the `MyComponent1` itself 
unlike the one in `MyComponent2` it's the one that was provided from `app.module`